# In Locust I need to get original timeout or connection error when using catch_response=True to validate response

Tags: locust

There is a good explanation how to validate response of the request
https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/writing-a-locustfile.html#validating-responses

However there are cases when status_code=0 (case of connection error or timeout).
I would like to be able to pass original error when it happens in response.failure().
For example:

```
with self.client.get("/some_test_url/", catch_response=True) as response:
    if response.status_code == 200 and _some_other_errors_checks_:
        response.failure("Response is 200 but contain _some_error_")
    if response.status_code == 0: # This is case of timeout or connection error
        response.failure(????????)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could see the original error using `response.error` property.

If something happened and the response is an error response or contains an error you could raise the original error using `response.raise_for_status()` that will throw the original error of the response if exists

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just to confirm that you suggest something like this

`if response.status_code == 0: # This is case of timeout or connection error
        response.raise_for_status()`

Comment: That it's one of the usage that apply to what I have write. But in fact you don't need to check the `status_code == 0` because the call to `response.raise_for_status()` will only raise an error if there is an error in the response, otherwise it will do nothing. Also you could even check for response.error to check if there is an error and get/inspect the error type and messages, that perhaps it will be better to raise it and catch it with several except clauses for different error types